# Проблема с разбитием строки

Tags: c++

Вроде бы изначально казалось что простое задание, но почему-то не получается добиться оптимального результата.

"Программа ждет ввода строки неограниченной длины.
Затем программа ждет ввода символа.
После чего она должна разбить первую строку в другие подстроки, используя второй параметр в виде разделителя и вывести на экран."

Могу скинуть свой кривой код:

```
std::string str;
std::cout << "Введите строку: ";
std::getline(std::cin, str);

char symb;
std::cout << "Введите разделяющий символ: ";
std::cin >> symb;

int check = 0;
std::vector<std::string> arr;

for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    std::string temp = "";

    if (str[i] == symb && check == 0) { temp = str.substr(0, i); arr.emplace_back(temp); check=i; }

    if (str[i] == symb && check != i)           
    {
        int index = i;
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < str.size(); j++)
        {
            if (str[j] == symb)                 
            {   
                temp = str.substr(index + 1, j);
                arr.emplace_back(temp);
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}


for (auto &el : arr)
{
    std::cout << el << std::endl;
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Comment: а символ-разделитель должен входить в разибые строки? Я ввожу Test string и символ s, какой должен быть результат? Te, t , tring или Te, st , string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось так:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string str = "Test string";
//  std::cout << "Введите строку: ";
//  std::getline(std::cin, str);

    char symb = 's';
//  std::cout << "Введите разделяющий символ: ";
//  std::cin >> symb;

    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    size_t last_index = 0;

    // Разбиваем по символу разделителю
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == symb)
        {
            // В массив складываем подстроки и запоминаем индекс символа-разделителя, если найден
            arr.emplace_back(str.substr(last_index, i - last_index));
            last_index = i /*+ 1*/; // +1, если символ-разделитель не должен попадать в подстроки
        }
    }

    // Всё что осталось в строке - последний элемент, тоже закидываем в вектор
    arr.emplace_back(str.substr(last_index, str.size() - last_index));


    for (auto &el : arr)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << el << "]" << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Вывод:

```
[Te]
[st ]
[string]
```

Или так:

```
[Te]
[t ]
[tring]
```

Comment: В условии этого не сказано, но думаю что логичнее было бы, если бы символ разделитель не входил в строку.

Comment: @bard, +1 раскоментите и тогда не будет входить)

Comment: Да, вижу. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @bard, если ответ правильный, то отмечайте его как правильный